# WinRT app closed due to suspend timing out when device is resuming from sleep

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10

I've been dealing with a fault found during testing that I can't seem to get to the bottom of.  I have a Windows 8.1 application running on a laptop on Windows 10.  The user was using the application, left the laptop for a couple of hours, when they came back the application had disappeared and had lost the data that hadn't yet been saved.  This has happened twice on the same machine.

Digging through the Event Viewer on the machine, it appears the following scenario happened:

1. Application was started
2. Device went into suspend
3. Device resumed
4. During the resume process, the following event appeared in the Event Log:

   `Package XXX+App was terminated because it took too long to suspend.`

Running through the suspend mode using the Visual Studio tools it seems to take around 300ms to run the code that saves the current state.

I don't understand why the application would be suspending while the device itself was resuming.  Could this be a case of the app suspend started before the device suspended, and when the device resumed it decided it'd had long enough?  In which case what is the correct way to handle this?

Or is this something completely different?  I'm not certain where to go with this and can't seem to find any documentation that covers the app suspend/resume in conjunction with a device suspend/resume.

Thanks

Comment: In the suspend event are doing anything async?

Comment: Yes I am, however I am doing `e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral()` at the start and doing `deferral.Complete();` at the end, this whole process typically takes no more than 400ms